# DOS program debug in IDA?

Tags: ida, debugging, dos

Does anybody know something hack to debug 16bit DOS program in IDA 6.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IDA DOSBox plugin](https://github.com/wjp/idados) by Eric Fry.

Note that it requires a modified DOSBox build.

Comment: Not to mention (and this is a pretty big one) - it requires the IDA SDK, which requires a paid version of IDA.  IDA costs up to $3000.  Not exactly within everyone's price range.

Comment: @Jez the OP mentioned IDA 6.1, which is not freeware, so presumably they had the SDK.

Comment: For anyone wanting this and doesn't have the SDK, have a look here for the compiled files (not mine): https://github.com/lab313ru/idados_dosbox. Found them there. I was able to compile the plw plugin (especially to enable debugging on Linear Executable files as said in an Issue on the repo), but DOSBox was being harder, so I found that one (btw, if anyone tries to compile the EXE, the C++ standard must be set to at most C++14 in all Makefiles).

Comment: Aside from this, anyone who needs this for newer IDA Pro versions, check this one out which is made by the same person who compiled those 2 files: https://github.com/lab313ru/dsbxida. Uses DOSBox-X it seems.